# How can I keep control+d from disconnecting my session?

Tags: linux, command-line, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I regularly ssh to a centos 5 box. Somehow they keys are mapped so that `control+d` will log me out of my current shell. If I am sudo'ed to another use it puts me back to the previous user. If I am not sudo'ed it just disconnects me. How can I keep this from happening? I regularly use control+d to cancel out of the python interpreter and sometimes I accidentally press it more than once.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You're looking for the `IGNOREEOF` environment variable if you use `bash`:

```
IGNOREEOF
```

> Controls the action of an interactive shell on receipt of an EOF character as the sole input.
>         If  set,  the  value  is  the number of consecutive EOF characters which must be typed as the
>         first characters on an input line before bash exits.  If the variable  exists  but  does  not
>         have  a  numeric  value, or has no value, the default value is 10.  If it does not exist, EOF
>         signifies the end of input to the shell.

So `export IGNOREEOF=42` and you'll have to press <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> fourty-two times before it actually quits your shell.

POSIX [`set`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/set.html) has an `-o ignoreeof` setting too. So consult your shell's documentation to see if your shell has this (it should), and to check its exact semantics.

Comment: Nice, gives a "Use exit to leave the shell" message, at least on Ubuntu. Being su'd into a user, you probably don't want to inadvertently leave it, esp if the parent user is root level.

Comment: I personally find that really annoying, so I don't set it anywhere. Found out about these while trying to _disable_ that behavior :)

Comment: I can't resist being a pedant. `IGNOREEOF` is the number of times the EOF is ignored before finally accepting it. So in your example above, if you `export IGNOREEOF=42`, you will need to press CONTROL-D 43 times to exit--not 42.

Answer (score 4):

If you really don't like having <kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd>, then you could remove the `eof` character in the terminal controls.

```
stty eof undef
```

After this, <kbd>Cntl-d</kbd> will be any other control character.

Comment: I just tried that in a terminal (urxvt) with bash, and in a plain console, and it did not work.

Comment: Hmm... that used to work and docs still say that it does.  An alternative would be to use <kbd>Ctrl-[</kvd>.

Comment: This would also make it no longer exit from python.

Comment: Now `Ctrl-d` returns: `zsh: do you wish to see all 5980 possibilities` @Arcege

Answer (score 2):

tcsh `set ignoreeof` or `set ignoreeof=<any value not 1>` works

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file so that it includes this line

```
SetEnv IGNOREEOF=3
```

This appears to do what you want. It prevents accidental SSH disconnects, while still allowing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to exit from subshells.

Details can be found in `man sshd_config` and `man bash`

Answer (score -1):

**The Bug**

I had a similar problem, if I used <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> to debug and happened to use it one extra time than intended it closed the whole tab.

---

**Suggestion Using Environment Variables**

*Temporary (only for your current session):*

```
export IGNOREEOF=20
```

or

```
set ignoreeof=20
```

After setting it, you can print to check if it got set:

```
printenv
```

You can also unset it:

```
unset ignoreeof
```

*Permanent:*

Open, edit and set the environment variable for good, for example using sublime

`subl ~/.bashrc` or `subl ~/.bash_profile` and add `export IGNOREEOF=15` at the end of the file to set the environmental variables permanently. To do that automatically you can try this in you console:

```
echo "export IGNOREEOF=20" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

You can also check the current value by using echo like this:

```
echo $IGNOREEOF
```

If you have set the value correctly, it should print the value to your terminal. If the value is not set, it will just print an empty line.

**Summarizing**

Try this:

```
export IGNOREEOF=20 && echo "export IGNOREEOF=20" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Hope this helps, have a great day!