# ksh - map Ctrl-D to exit shell

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ksh, exit

I would like to know how we can map the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> in ksh to exit the shell as it does in bash shell.

Not much familiar with key binding in ksh.

#### Edit

See my comments below.

```sh
$ echo $0
bash
$ exit    # I pressed Ctrl-D here, 'exit' string was placed and the shell exited

$> echo $0
ksh
$> Use 'exit' to leave ksh  # I pressed Ctrl-D here, Got this message and returned to the ksh prompt
$> echo $0
ksh
$> cat >> somefile
Some text
$>   # I pressed Ctrl-D here. So this key combination is taken as eof char for file, but not for exit.
```

So, it's needs <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to be mapped to exit the shell? How do I do that?

Comment: If you enter ^D after some characters, it isn't heeded as "end of file". It must go on a line on its own.

Comment: Ctrl+D should work in the same way in bash and ksh. What different behavior do you observe?

Comment: @vonbrand Please see my update.

Comment: It works the same. Just that bash writes `exit` when exiting, ksh doesn't.

Comment: @vonbrand No, it isn't exiting the ksh. That's what I showed. Please check. I am still on ksh shell. It has not exitted.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (ASCII `EOT`) **already is** mapped to exiting the shell, in both `vi` and `emacs` modes, as the `ksh93` manual page explains.  It's quite evidently so from your script capture.

The manual page also explains what others have commented here, that this key only has this effect if the line is empty.  (This mimics the standard behaviour of the line discipline in cooked mode.)

What you are missing, which is also explained by the manual page, is that you have the `ignoreeof` option set on.  So the Korn Shell has seen the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on an empty line, and ignored it, printing the very message that you see, to explain that with `ignoreeof` set on you must explicitly use the `exit` command.

So forget about `stty` and trap handlers, as in the other answer; and simply:

```
set -o noignoreeof
```

## Further reading

- [How can I keep control+d from disconnecting my session?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27588/5132) — a question wanting to achieve the opposite has an answer that is the opposite

Answer (score 1):

You want the [`stty`](http://man.cx/stty) command: see how ^D is mapped with `stty -a`. You can change that to something else with `stty eof char`: Remove the "eof" setting with `stty eof undef`

---

Untested: you want to read about the `trap` command in the ksh man page. It might be sufficient for you to set up a handler for the `EXIT` signal.

```
# warning: completely untested
exit_handler() { echo "exit"; exit; }
trap exit_handler EXIT
```

Comment: To remove a terminal binding, use `^-` or `undef` as the key, e.g. `stty eof under`. This is specified in POSIX.

Comment: @glenn Please see my update.