# Exit shell with shortcut (not typing exit) that closes session properly

Tags: bash, shell, session

I use a ProxyJump command for a number of ssh sessions I use daily, and also switch users a lot on these sessions and having to type `exit` 3 or 4 times in a row isn't too fun.

I am aware of `newline` + `~` + `.` to terminate an ssh session, I still have to check if it terminates it amicably like an `exit` would, but how do you exit all sessions in the current shell with a single command or shortcut such that typing `exit` 3 or 4 times in my case becomes a one-time thing?

Comment: `~.` just disconnects your SSH client (it's useful when the network has disappeared, for example).  Normally, the SSH daemon will recognise that and signal its session with `SIGHUP`, so it's not quite the same as quitting the shell normally (but it's useful if you can't get any response from the shell).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> will exit a shell in many cases. It is quicker than typing `exit` <kbd>Enter</kbd>. It's still not a single command to terminate everything, but holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hitting <kbd>D</kbd> several times is easier and faster. Not sure how valuable this is for your use case.

Discussed in detail [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110248/62481).

Comment: The next stop is https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182071/5132 , and the stop after that is the further reading there.  (-:

Comment: Be careful with CTRL+D. In bash, if you have input any characters in your prompt, hitting CTRL+D will execute it the same way Enter would. In other words, don’t type out an `rm` command and then hit CTRL+D if you didn’t want to execute it. I don’t see this behavior in ksh.

Comment: @Peschke On every system I've ever used Ctrl+D does nothing if I've typed something. I've never seen the behavior you describe.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I tested and confirmed the behavior at the time of my comment with bash on RHEL 7.5.

Comment: @Peschke I can't confirm this on CentOS 7.3. Maybe it's depending on which terminal you use?

Comment: Peschke is using the `vi` terminal input bindings.

Comment: That's fine I can just mash CTRL+D a few times and get the job done. Thank you.

Comment: @JdeBP: That’s true. I forgot about other input bindings. I still don’t see this issue in ksh. Must be on bash only with vi input bindings.

Answer (score 6):

Typing `~.` actually *does* the trick of closing all the "nested" connections through to the deepest.

It does so with the amicable exit you want as long as all your shells are configured to handle SIGHUP as a graceful death. Bash does so by default. You can easily check the amicable exit for your set-up by e.g. seeing whether the `.bash_history` files of your deeper sessions get properly updated after the `~.`, or if you set your bash-es not to update .bash_history upon exit then you might set a `trap` on the EXIT event (or in your `~/.bash_logout`) with a command that writes something somewhere and later see whether it got executed.

Besides, I’m not sure what you mean by "exit all sessions in current shell". Each interactive bash is just one session, and the commands you type go always only to the deepest shell of the ProxyJump chain. If you meant "the background jobs in the current shell", bash does send SIGHUP to all its jobs on receiving SIGHUP by the ssh daemon upon the `~.` , therefore such exit should be fully amicable if those running jobs react properly to a SIGHUP.