# Exit out of "all levels" of SSH connection?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

E.g. when I SSH into a server and then `sudo bash` and then `su <user>` to do some work, I want a quick way to exit all shells back to my local terminal.

### going in

When I have to do some work on a *server* as *jim*.

```bsh
local > ssh me@server
server:me > sudo bash
server:root > su jim
server:jim > // do stuff as jim
```

### going out

When my work is complete but I don't want to leave the shells logged in.

```bsh
server:jim > exit
server:root > exit
server:me > exit
local > // after 3 commands
```

### preferred way out

Here's how I'd like to do it.

```bsh
server:jim > exitall // for example
local > // after one command
```

Comment: Does `ENTER ~ .` meet your requirements?

Comment: Do you need to do anything as root? If not you could run `exec sudo su - jim` as the command on the server, and then `exit` will take you all the way out.

Comment: I don't think Linux does this, but `stty 0` on some systems will drop your connection.

Comment: Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/507011/exit-shell-with-shortcut-not-typing-exit-that-closes-session-properly

Comment: @icarus Thanks for the tip to skip root -- very obvious now that you mention it. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're open to a proactive (vs retroactive) solution, consider using `exec` for the intermediate steps that you want to bypass on the way out:

#### going in (modified):

```
local > ssh me@server
server:me > exec sudo bash
server:root > exec su jim
server:jim > // do stuff as jim
```

#### going out

```
server:jim > exit
local > // after 1 command
```

Using `exec` replaces your current shell with the listed command; as a result, when you `exit` out of jim's shell, your root shell exits, which then causes the `sudo bash` shell to exit, leaving you back where you started.

Comment: Cool, I'll give it a go!

Answer (score 3):

I found the fastest way is to use Ctrl + D as many times as needed which will terminate each bash session

Comment: Great, thanks! I'll try it out.