# Re-mapping EOF (ctrl+D) in bash

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

If I'm in a `bash` shell, because of how `stty` is set up, typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will send an `EOF` to `bash`, which will then do pretty much the same thing as the command `exit` does, and exits the shell.

I'm wondering if there's some way I can temporarily re-map it so that `bash` does not exit upon recieving an `EOF`, but instead executes some other command of my choosing.

---

My motivation is that I'm using Python virtualenvs (through `virutalenvwrapper`). `workon foo` will enter the virtualenv, and `deactivate` will leave the virtualenv.

Sometimes, `deactivate` can be used for clean-up, but when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, it skips that step.

If I could make it so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> either (A) ran `deactivate` and just exited the virtualenv (and re-mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to `exit` again) so I could continue my shell, or (B) ran `deactivate` and then `exit` so it would still exit the shell but the clean-up would be performed, that would be great.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27588 for how to let the shell ignore EOF.

Comment: @Bodo That will let me stop Ctrl+D from exiting the shell, but it won't really help me re-map it to something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could trap `EXIT` to run a specific command/function when the shell exits.

```
trap deactivate EXIT
```

will run `deactivate` just before exiting the shell.

See http://redsymbol.net/articles/bash-exit-traps/ for more examples.

Comment: Thank you; this worked. I added `trap deactivate EXIT` to the `postactivate` file for the environment, and added `trap - EXIT` to the `postdeactivate` file. This accomplishes (B) from the question.