# Difference between "IGNOREEOF=n" variable and "ignoreeof=n" word usage?

Tags: bash, set

When i use `ignoreeof` of `set` builtin, i realized "IGNOREEOF=n" variable and "ignoreeof=n" word can usable for limitation. For example;

```
└─$ bash
└─$ set -o ignoreeof
└─$ IGNOREEOF=2
└─$
Use "exit" to leave the shell.
└─$
Use "exit" to leave the shell.
└─$
exit
```

```
└─$ bash
└─$ set -o ignoreeof
└─$ ignoreeof=2
└─$
Use "exit" to leave the shell.
└─$
Use "exit" to leave the shell.
└─$
exit
```

I know "*IGNOREEOF=n*" is variable but i don't know what is "*ignoreeof=n*". I'm looked `set` and `env` output, "**IGNOREEOF**" there is but "**ignoreeof**" is not.

Comment: Here `set | grep ignoreeof` returns `SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:ignoreeof:interactive-comments:monitor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The man page says of `set -o ignoreeof` that:

> The effect is as if the shell command 'IGNOREEOF=10' had been executed

That's quite literal, actually:

```
$ echo $IGNOREEOF

$ set -o ignoreeof
$ echo $IGNOREEOF
10
```

Doing the opposite, `set +o ignoreeof` unsets `IGNOREEOF`, and `SHELLOPTS` seems to contain `ignoreeof` when `IGNOREEOF` is set (regardless of it's set via assignment to it, or `set -o ignoreeof`). (I tested with Bash 4.4.)

<strike>The lowercase variable `ignoreeof` probably does nothing special.</strike>

Odd as it is, the lowercase variable `ignoreeof` seems to be some sort of an undocumented equivalent to the uppercase one. So changing either changes the count of EOFs required, which I suppose is what you hit in the second example.

[According to the maintainer](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2021-03/msg00183.html), the lowercase one

> exists only for backwards compatibility; it's deprecated and has been
> for years

In general though, `set -o` flags and variables are distinct things.

Comment: For this reason, even if the ignoreeof setting is not turned on, when we manually define a number in the `IGNOREEOF` variable(for example IGNOREEOF=2), the same function works.This is not bug right ? If I understand it correctly, ignoreeof setting only define IGNOREEOF variable?

Comment: For clarification;; https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27591/364572

Comment: @testter, yeah, it looks like in Bash, `IGNOREEOF=10` and `set -o ignoreeof` are exactly equal. The latter is POSIX, the former lets you pick the number you like...