# putty - ctrl + d doesn't work (ctrl + shift + d does)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, putty

I'm connected to a Linux server over ssh using `putty`.

Usually in Linux you can delete characters you typed in the command prompt with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>. But on Windows with `putty` this does not work.

The behavior that usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> has is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd>.

But this is unconvenient and I would like `putty` to act like a Linux terminal.

`stty -a` says:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 50; columns 189; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O;
min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

Is there any way I can change this behaviour of `putty`?

Comment: I do not have such problem. I assume your `TERM` is wrong. Select a new one. Or screen/tmux/... may interfere with keys

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi `echo $TERM` outputs `xterm`. Setting `TERM=linux` in `.bash_profile` doesn't help. `tmux` and `screen` are installed but not running.

Comment: So your remote computer uses xterm (which it is wrong to hardcode). But what is the TERM which putty is using and telling the remote computer about such use (which with your hard coding of TERM, it will be ignored).

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi The `terminal-type string` in the Putty configuration is also `xterm`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread your question. In any case, on last 25 years control-D was always EOF. But manual give you a hints: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Text.html : so remote EOF binding in stty, see second answer in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27588/how-can-i-keep-controld-from-disconnecting-my-session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a different Windows application that used <kbd>ctrl + d</kbd>...
That took a long time to find out...